# $\mathbb{R}$ can be shown as a countable union of sets with empty interior

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I want to show that $\mathbb{R}$ can be shown as a countable union of sets with empty interior. note that the question doesn't mention that these sets are closed, so the question doesn't have any contradiction with Baire theorem.

any idea to prove?

Comment: Isn't it enough to say $\mathbb R=\mathbb Q \cup (\mathbb R \backslash \mathbb Q)$?

Comment: @MarcoDisce yeah. thx. I thought that it was a very difficult problem, I never thought about it in this way :)) thank U so much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact, you can write $\mathbb{R}$ as the union of **two** sets with empty interior - what's the "biggest" set with empty interior you can think of? (HINT: Are you familiar with density?)

Comment: This doesn't sound like an irrational approach.

Comment: As somebody has written in comments they are $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q^C}$. I never thought about them :)) thank U so much

Answer (score 3):

You can do more. You can write $\mathbb R$ as a countable union of pairwise disjoint translates of the same set with empty interior:

On $\mathbb R$ define the equivalence relation $x~y$ if and only if $x-y \in \mathbb Q$. Pick a system of representatives (i.e. one element from each set) for this equivalence relation and call this set $B$.

Then $B$ has empty interior, $(t+B)\cap (s+B)=\emptyset\,$ if $\,t,s$ are distinct rationals and 
$$\mathbb R = \cup_{t \in \mathbb Q} t+B$$

Answer (score 2):

The rationals and the irrationals have empty interior. If you want a countably infinite family let $F=\{\{q\}:q\in Q\}\cup \{R\backslash Q\}.$

Comment: As you wrote the union, isn't it that $F$ consists of singletons of rationals, and irrational numbers ?

Comment: yes. singleton sets of rationals and the set of irrationals.

Comment: But then I can not understand what you mean. Shouldn't it be $F=\{q:q\in\mathbb Q\}\cup\{\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q\}$

Comment: @Svetoslav 9 . No. What you have written for F is equal to R itself. The $F$ that I defined  is a family of subsets of $R$, with $\cup F=R$.

Comment: If we take only the part $F_1=\{\{q\}:q\in Q\}$, then $\cup F_1=\{q:q\in Q\}$

Comment: But $F_1\cup \{R\setminus Q\}$ has what elements ? I am just a bit confused now.

Comment: Ok, right, sorry !